# How to insert email from sql query if checkbox is marked in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have problem with sending mails to more than one user. To be specific, i have table from database. I have id_user, name, surname, email... in one line ( tag). First column is checkbox with name= **$row['id_user']**.

If i check ect. 5 users, i need to send them same message, and that works.

I just need some kind of idea how to fill **$emailAll** array .
Do i need to do submit method? In that case, i need to transfer all data to new php file with array?

Thanks!
:)

```
href="mailto:<?php $len = count($emailAll);
                                    $i= 0;
                                    while ($i< $len){
                                        echo $emailAll[$i] .";";
                                        $i++;}?>"
```

Comment: You say "table from database". But when you say "table" do you actually mean a HTML table in your page? Because databases don't have checkboxes.

Comment: If you want to adjust your "href" link based on which checkboxes the user ticked, then yes you could submit the data to your server and have php re-create the page with the link changed. Or you could do it with Javascript without needing to refresh everything.

Comment: ADyson, yes! They are seperated..that's problem because everithing i have in common is: name of checkbox tag (HTML) and id_user  (SQL) are same

Comment: Java should be much better choice..what should i do? Onclick function with comparing name of tag and id_user and then pull info of email from database based on id_user value?

Comment: JavaScript, not Java - they are very different things! Yes you could do that. Or have the email address already hidden in a data-attribute of the checkbox, perhaps.

Comment: Yes yes, i meant JavaScript :) that is actually good idea..but i made this while loop for input data from array. I need something like if (checkbox is on) insert into array. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do as per my knowledge

Make your checkbox as an array as below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="email" />
```

Send this other or same PHP file then using the form and you will receive an array emails

Then iterate this emails array and make coma separated email in one variable and send the email

```
$emailId="";
foreach ($_POST['emails'] $key => $email) {
    $emailId.=",".$email;
}

    $from = "test@test.com";
    $to = $emailId;
    $subject = "Checking PHP mail";
    $message = "PHP mail works just fine";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)) {
        echo "The email message was sent.";
    } else {
        echo "The email message was not sent.";
    }
```